# Capifony & Symfony 2 error: php bin/vendors install --reinstall

Tags: deployment, symfony, capifony

I have a big problem.

I had a configuration which worked properly till today.

I don't know why I have now this error

```
*** [err :: server.com] Could not open input file: bin/vendors
    command finished in 312ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/server/deploy/releases/20120301143822; true"
    servers: ["server.com"]
    [server.com] executing command
    command finished in 208ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/server/deploy/releases/20120301143822 && php bin/vendors install --reinstall'" on server.com
```

I precise that I deploy my local work to production

here is my deploy file

```
set   :application,   "MyApp"
set   :deploy_to,     "/home/server/deploy"
set   :serverName,    "myServer.com" # The server's hostname
set   :domain,        "server.com"

set   :scm,           :git
set   :repository,    "file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/localWorkDev"
set   :deploy_via,    :rsync_with_remote_cache

role  :web,           domain
role  :app,           domain
role  :db,            domain, :primary => true

set   :use_sudo,      false
set   :keep_releases, 3
set   :user,          "root"

set   :shared_files,      ["app/config/parameters.ini"]
set   :shared_children,     [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads", "vendor"]
set   :update_vendors, true
```

Please help me

Thanks

Sam

Comment: Could you check for the permissions for file bin/vendors on your production server. I guess it's either not there or you don't have the correct permissions!

Comment: Hi thank you Boo... how can I control it? I have found another solution but it doesn't suit me. I have change "set   :deploy_via,    :rsync_with_remote_cache" by "set   :deploy_via,    :copy" and it works. I think my rsync files is corrupted... How can I do to reinit them?

Comment: Can you tell what the problem was? If it worked till today, there must be some kind of change which you might not be aware of. I don't know if you use capifony from windows or linux, but if you are on windows rsync might be the problem. There are some weird things going on when deploying to a linux web server from a windows machine with rsync. We found no solution to the weird permissions (mainly root:root) which are used even if you log in as another user!

Comment: Hi Boo. I am an OS X, and I have a problem when he does this operation: executing "rsync -a --delete /home/server/deploy/shared/cached-copy/ /home/server/deploy/releases/20120301204641/". So when it bugs at this line I make a CTRL+C combinaison in order to stop this command. I have made some operations and I think I have removed the .rsync folder and I have recreate it... I don't remember in which copy I have made it... Maybe it's the problem?

Comment: Did you update your Symfony2 version? Because, there was a change on how to manage vendors. It now uses Composer instead of this `bin/vendors` script. Also, Capifony 2.1.7 should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALL is right now. I have just done a

```
php bin/vendors install --reinstall
```

and now it works.

In my case, it was very important to add **`--reinstall`** command.

Hope it would be usefull

Sam